How to reserve space with specified width and height in Label in Tkinter?
I'm trying to make a small gallery program in Python for personal use but couldn't succeed yet. The problem I'm having is, reserving spaces with specified sizes in pixel (128, 128) that will be embedded images when in view.
When I specify width and height with no image or text on Label creation, they become too big like this:
https://i.sstatic.net/EDS7DXGZ.png
Likewise, when I don't specify width and height, they become so small and mess with scrollbar.
Below is the code I came up with. When running it with _add_grid function, they are organized nicely because images are embedded on creation, but I couldn't make add_grid give me the right results.
I based this code on answers in this question.
import tkinter as tk
from dataclasses import dataclass
from os import scandir
from sys import argv
from threading import Thread
from typing import Callable

from PIL import Image, ImageTk, UnidentifiedImageError


@dataclass
class Pos:
    row: int = 0
    col: int = 0
    max_row: int = -1
    max_col: int = 4


def list_files(
    path: str,
    for_each: Callable[[str], None] | None = None,
    on_end: Callable[[], None] | None = None,
):
    with scandir(path) as scan:
        for file in scan:
            if file.is_file() is True:
                if for_each is not None:
                    for_each(file.path)
    if on_end is not None:
        on_end()


def _add_grid(master, pos: Pos, path: str):
    try:
        image = Image.open(path)
    except UnidentifiedImageError:
        return
    image.thumbnail((128, 128))
    image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = tk.Label(master, image=image_tk)
    label.image = image_tk
    label.grid(row=pos.row, column=pos.col, sticky="news")
    print(pos.col, pos.row)
    pos.col += 1
    if pos.col >= pos.max_col:
        pos.col = 0
        pos.row += 1


def set_view_image(label: tk.Label, path: str):
    image = Image.open(path)
    image.thumbnail((128, 128))
    label.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image=label.image)
    return


def visibility_listener(e: tk.Event, label: tk.Label, path: str):
    match e.state:
        case "VisibilityUnobscured" | "VisibilityPartiallyObscured":
            Thread(target=set_view_image, args=(label, path), daemon=True).start()
        case "VisibilityFullyObscured":
            label.config(image="")
            label.image = None
        case _:
            print(e)


def add_grid(master: tk.Widget, pos: Pos, path: str, labels: list[list[tk.Label]]):
    label = tk.Label(master, width=128, height=128)
    label.bind("<Visibility>", lambda e: visibility_listener(e, label, path))
    label.grid(row=pos.row, column=pos.col, sticky=tk.NSEW)
    try:
        labels[pos.row].append(label)
    except IndexError:
        labels.append([label])
    pos.col += 1
    if pos.col >= pos.max_col:
        pos.col = 0
        pos.row += 1


def main():
    path = argv[1]
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("550x500")
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    main_frame.grid(sticky="news")
    main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame.grid_propagate(False)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    def _scroll(e):
        canvas.yview_scroll(-1 if e.num == 4 else 1, tk.UNITS)

    image_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
    canvas.bind_all("<Button-5>", _scroll)
    canvas.bind_all("<Button-4>", _scroll)
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=image_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

    labels: list[list[tk.Label]] = []
    pos = Pos()

    def on_end():
        image_frame.update_idletasks()
        bbox = canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)
        w, h = bbox[2] - bbox[1], bbox[3] - bbox[1]
        print(f"w: {w}, h: {h}")
        dw, dh = int((w / 4) * 3), int((h / pos.row) * 5)
        print(f"dw: {dw}, dh: {dh}")
        canvas.config(width=dw, height=dh, scrollregion=bbox)

    Thread(
        target=list_files,
        kwargs={
            "path": path,
            "for_each": lambda p: add_grid(image_frame, pos, p, labels),
            "on_end": on_end,
        },
        daemon=True,
    ).start()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The width and height attributes in tk.Label are in characters not pixels.  Does this explain why they are too big.

I read somewhere that if not specified, width and height units are considered pixel but I guess this doesn't apply to Label, thank you.

You can force the Label to use dimensions in pixels by including an image in the label.
def add_grid(master: tk.Widget, pos: Pos, path: str, labels:   list[list[tk.Label]]):
    label = tk.Label(master, width=128, height=128, image=dummy)

where dummy can be any image but I usually use a one-pixel transparent gif.

This for some reason had a strange effect, Labels go haywire when switching the images and this solution isn't fit for my usage since I want to lower the RAM usage. I solved this by creating the Label on top of a new Frame, which behaves as expected with specified dimensions.

@FalconSN One global 1x1 image consumes neglectable memory comparable to adding a frame widget to each label in the grid.

@acw1668 that makes sense, I didn't think of it that way. I will keep this in mind, thank you two.
